# How to handle the situation when server is down on my android side

Tags: android, http-post

Here is my doInBackground() method in which I call my makeHttpRequest() method which is in other class.

```
 protected String doInBackground(Integer... args) {
            // Building Parameters

            String parameter1 = "tenant";
                String parameter2 = "price";

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("person",parameter1));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price",parameter2));

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(requiredurl, "POST", params);


            Log.d("Details", json.toString());



                int success = json.getInt("connected");

                if (success == 1) {

                    //blah blah
                      }
        }
```

**makeHttpRequest() method:**

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){

                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }       

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       ................
       ....................... // Here the result is extracted and made it to json object
       .............................

        // return JSON 
        return jObj;  // returning the json object to the method that calls.

    }
```

So, by the above code, the actual call to the server is made by this line ->  `HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);`

When my server is up everything works fine, but when it is down the progress bar continuously loads. I want to handle this situation. Have done lot of search, but could find only this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109473/handling-server-down-while-calling-rest-web-services). This looks good for my situation because even my thought is to wait for the 10 seconds to get the response and if it exceeds that time out, I need to handle it to show the message in the catch block. But I am unable to implement it according to my code. Can some one please help me on this? I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Add Following Code before executing the url.

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
```

write the above code in try block and Catch `ConnectTimeOutException` and `SocketConnectionTimeOutException`. Where you can show some custom dialog.

You can also judge it by checking the status line of HttpClient Response.

Comment: This answer is exactly same as in the link I provided in my question. Can you please clarify what is this HttpConnectionParams in your answer and how to do according to my code. This is where I got stuck with that answer?

Comment: @Korhan Sorry I haven't noticed that link. However this answer should work for you. if you set HttpConnectionParams then while executing the url if there is any problem with socket, it wait till the timeout milliseconds you provided and then throws SocketTimeoutException. the same applicable for Connection Time out also. If Server is down and you are unable to connect to it then it will wait till connection establishment and if not success then throw ConnectionTimeoutException.

Answer (score 1):

Your exceptions are not getting hit because the HttpClient is not throwing an exception. Perhaps you are getting an error in your HttpResponse code, such as a 500. In your try block, add this line:

```
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

Then read the status code. If your web server is up you should get a 200 OK, but if it's down, you'll probably get a 500 or something else. You can then handle the code here where your spinning progress bar needs to be hidden, and an error message can be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Will check with this if I can't get with the try catch. BTW Can you please detail on the exact status codes?